# How to remove the mantine default table line

Tags: css, frontend, border, outline, mantine

I want to remove the default line in mantine table, i try to change it using css but it is not a border nor outline. please help me :(((  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIfxz.png)

Comment: Please add your code to the question, not images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <tr key={element.name + element.price}>
  <td style={{ border: 0 }}>
    <Flex direction="column">
      <Text fw={600}>{element.name}</Text>
      <Text>{element.address}</Text>
    </Flex>
  </td>
  <td style={{ border: 0 }}>
    <Text fw={600}>₹{element.price}</Text>
  </td>
  <td style={{ border: 0 }}>
    <Badge>{element.status}</Badge>
  </td>
</tr>
```

you can apply border 0 on the td or you can select the every td element that is inside the tr and give border 0 do the td with css child selector.

[mantine table without border bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8wPS.png)